# Showing $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y(E) = \mathcal{O}_X$ if and only if $E$ is effective.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

This arises from lemma 7.11 and remark 7.12 from the book ‘Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry’ by Debarre. Essentially, lemma 7.11 states the following:

“Let $f: Y\rightarrow X$ be a proper birational morphism between smooth varieties. Then for any **effective** divisor $E$ on $Y$ contained in the exceptional locus of $f$, one has $f_*\mathcal{O}(Y)(E) \cong \mathcal{O}_X$.”

Now suppose $F$ is any exceptional divisor of $f$. We write $F = F_1 -F_2$ as a difference of effective divisors, where $F_1$ and $F_2$ have no common components. Certainly, $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y(F) = f_*\mathcal{O}_Y(F_1-F_2)$ injects into the sheaf $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y(F_1) \cong \mathcal{O}_X$.

The author then states that ‘it is therefore a sheaf of ideals that defines a subscheme of $X$ supported on $f(F_2)$. It follows $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y(F) \cong \mathcal{O}_X$ iff $F$ is effective.’

My understanding is that if $f_* \mathcal{O}_Y(F) \cong \mathcal{O}_X$. Then $F_2$ must be zero necessarily. How do we conclude that in this case $F_2 =0$? Any help given would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y(F) \cong \mathcal{O}_X$ then by pullback-pushforward adjunction there is a morphism
$$
\mathcal{O}_Y \cong f^*\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y(F).
$$
Moreover, on the locus where $f$ is an isomorphism, this morphism is the identity. This shows that $F$ is an effective divisor supported on the exceptional locus of $f$.

Comment: Hi @Sasha, thank you for your reply. May I ask for more details? I understand that on $Y- \operatorname{Exc}(f)$, both sides are isomorphic. How do we then deduce from here that $F$ must be effective?

Comment: @Soby: A morphism from $\mathcal{O}_Y$ corresponds to a global regular section of the line bundle, and being regular it has zeroes but not poles.

Comment: I think I understand, but I just a small query. So denote the morphism by $s: \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Y(F)$. So this corresponds to a global section $s\in H^0(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y(F))$ So $\operatorname{div}(s) + F \ge 0$. We are done if $\operatorname{div}s\ge 0$. I still have one minor question, how do we know that $s$ must correspond to a regular section?

Comment: @Soby: A morphism from $\mathcal{O}$ to a line bundle IS THE SAME as a regular section of this line bundle.